# Checking for a function to be homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $h=(h_1,h_2):U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be one-one and continuous in a neighborhood $U$ of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $h(0)=0$ and $h_1$ harmonic. Then $h:U\to h(U)$ is bijective and continuous. If only these things are known, can i say that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. Since $f$ is one-one, $f^{-1}$ is well defined. Can i get the continuity of $f^{-1}$ or these conditions are insufficient for continuity of $f^{-1}$?

Comment: It follows from invariance of domain. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: @IshanBanerjee thanks alot for the reference, though it seems very unlikely that it is true, i was expecting some counter example :)